# Equation of the plane passing through a point and parallel to a given line

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I want to compute the equation of the plans passing through $P=(1,2,3)$ and parallel to the line $r:=\langle 0,1,2\rangle+t\langle1,1,0\rangle$.

Here is my attempt: Because the plane is parallel to $r$. I may find a vector orthogonal to $v=\langle1,1,0\rangle$, such as $b=\langle-1,1,2\rangle$ to get the normal vector of the plane and then claim that the eq of the given plane is: $-(x-1)+(y-2)+2(z-3)=0$. Am I right?

Comment: You found a plan that satisfy the initial conditions, but it is not the only one. There are distinct vector $b$ that are orthogonal to the Line $r$.

Comment: What other condition do I need to get a unique plane?

Comment: *All* the vectors orthogonal to $\langle 1,1,0\rangle$ could be the normal vector to your plane. This is classically called a *pencil* of planes. You would need to know another vector (not parallel to that one) to which the plane is parallel in order to get a unique plane.

Comment: @Alchemy you would need an other point on the plan or an other vector parallel to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the equation of the given plane of the form:
$$a(x-1)+b(y-2)+c(z-3)=0$$
Where $<a,b,c>$ represent the direction ratios of the normal vector to the plane.
Since the plane is parallel to the line, it's normal vector must be perpendicular to the given line and hence:
$$<a,b,c>.<1,1,0>=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a+b=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a=-b$$
Therefore you can have infinite such $c$ and $a$ which will give us a plane parallel to the given line.
The value of $c$ and $a$ is required to determine a unique plane